# Only allow specified command name but still allow additional arguments

Tags: java, java-stream

I am currently using this code to find a command that the user types in:

```
final Command command = commands.stream()
        .filter(cmd -> input.startsWith(cmd.getName()))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidInputException("unknown command"));
```

Every command class has its own `getName()` method. This is how the `getName()` method of `ExitCommand()` looks like:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "exit";
}
```

Unfortunately, with the current stream, `"exittttttt"` is also accepted. I can't use `.equals(cmd.getName())` though, because there are commands that have subsequent arguments after the command name.

For example:

```
@Override
public String getName() {
    return "delete track";
}
```

But the full command is `delete track <id>`.

Does anyone have an idea how to only allow the command name that is specified in each `getName()` method but also still allow further arguments?

**EDIT:**

Each command has its own `getArguments()` method. The method will return 0 for the `exit` command and 1 for the `delete track` command. Maybe this can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly because your condition is `startsWith`? If input is `"exittttttt"`, then your predicate will match `"exit"` in the stream (because `"exittttttt"` starts with `exit`). Do you maybe want to use `equals()` rather than `startsWith()`?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to find a way to fix my problem but I don't know how. My only options that I know of are .equals() and startWith() which both don't solve my problem

Comment: @ernest_k Please read my whole question

Comment: What separates the command from its argument? A space (as in example)?

Comment: Yes, just a space. Also, please see my edit.

Comment: May be an option, why don't `getName()` can be specific to command name and another method `getCommand()` can be specific to command with arguments so that it will be easy to differentiate @DonaldDuck

Comment: @Deadpool I already have that! `getCommandDescription()` returns a String with the full command. But how would you use that to solve my problem..? For example `public String getCommandDescription() { return "delete track <id>"; }`

Comment: Probably you should parse the input string into a Command instance, then compare the names.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Oh, that's a good idea. How would that work?

Comment: You need some sort of catalog of all available commands, with their allowed arguments. There isn't a general solution here, since there is no specific delimiter between command and arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is what always separates commands from arguments, then you can use

```
.filter(cmd -> (cmd.getArguments() == 0 && input.equals(cmd.getName()))
                 || input.startsWith(cmd.getName() + " "))
```

This checks that the input matches the command name exactly if the command supports no arguments, or the input has the command name followed by a space.

If commands supporting arguments may be called without arguments, then maybe this is the right predicate:

```
.filter(cmd -> (cmd.getArguments() == 0 && input.equals(cmd.getName()))
                 || input.equals(cmd.getName()) //no args passed
                 || input.startsWith(cmd.getName() + " "))
```

Comment: What if is there is the command `exit now 1` with argument `1`? This command would also go through the filter, as `exit` does, even though `exit now` and `exit` are different commands.

Comment: Also, input = `exit now` (no arguments) and command `exit`, is a counter-example

Comment: In general, for  input `x y` and cmd `x` the filter would let the input pass.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Not with the second way he posted

Comment: @EugenCovaci You're making sense, and I can't pretend that I understand all the variations here. If the command name can be composed of 2+ words, then this post assumes that the user entered all words of the command (may entail input validation). Otherwise, I should say this search based on substrings is the wrong solution to start with. OP would perhaps need to index various inputs to matching commands as a simple but reliable alternative `{exit=exitCmd, exit now=exitNowCmd}`. Unless the use-case is this simple, the solution has to be more sophisticated anyway. And I can't delete this post...

Comment: I don’t like performing expensive operations like string concatenation for the sole purpose of matching. How about `input.startsWith(cmd.getName()) && (input.length() == cmd.length() || input.chatAt(cmd.length() == ' ')`? Though, having the commands sorted by name and performing a binary search would be even more effcient…

Comment: @Holger `input.startsWith()` will again allow commands like `exitabcdefg` because it only checks if it starts with the command

Comment: @ernest_k I don't quite understand the problem with your second solution. It seemed to work for all my command (one-word, two-word and three-word commands). Why shouldn't I use this solution?

Comment: @DonaldDuck that’s why it is a good idea to read the entire expression instead of stopping after ⅓. Think about what the remaining part `&& (input.length() == cmd.length() || input.charAt(cmd.length() == ' ')` means…

Comment: @DonaldDuck I'm not suggesting that you do not. But the scenario that EugenCovaci mentioned can occur, but you know how it can be mitigated since you know more about how it's used. Also, you can validate the *assumption* that I mentioned.

Comment: @Holger How is this supposed to work `input.charAt(cmd.getName().length() == ' ')`? charAt() needs an int as its parameter but you use a boolean instead. Or did you make a mistake?

Comment: @DonaldDuck of course, it is supposed to be `input.charAt(cmd.getName().length()) == ' '`. Just forgot one close bracket. The `)` at the end belongs to the entire `||` term. The logic should be easy to understand. The prerequisite for a match is the common prefix, the either must apply, the length is the same (no arguments) or a space following the common prefix (command separated from the arguments by at least one space).

Answer (score 0):

What about this line:

```
final Command command = commands.stream()
        .filter(cmd -> (input.split(" +").length > 0 && input.split(" +")[0].equals(cmd.getName())))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidInputException("unknown command"));
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Your design need to be revisited. When we say a command, it will have options and arguments. In your case you are combining the command and option. Just seperate those out and use equals for command comparison.

```
delete -track <id>
```

- delete- command
- track- option can be identified with start of hyphen
- optional arguments